# how can I modify the property of a class in its subclasses?

Tags: swift, inheritance, overriding, overloading

```
class Animals{
    var name : String = "default"
    var age : Int = 0
    func Details()-> String{
        return "This animal is a \(name) and has \(age) years old."
    }
}


class Dogs : Animals{
    name = "dog"
}

class Cats : Animals{
    name = "cat"
}

var MyAnimal = Dogs()
```

I want to see this message : "This animal is a dog and has 0 years old."
But each time I receive this one : "This animal is a default and has 0 years old."

```
var HisAnimal = Cats()
```

Comment: A few side notes: Class names should be singular, and you should avoid added explicit type annotations where they're not strictly necessary, and variable names (such as `MyAnimal`) shouldBeLowerCamelCase.

Comment: For semantics, you might also want to rename the property `name` to e.g. `species`, and optionally keep the former in case you actually want to store the _name_ of say your neighbours dog (which hopefully is something along the line of `Fred` rather than `dog`). Moreover, since `species` would be a constant unique to the (sub-)type, you might let this be a (immutable) class property rather than an instance one.

Comment: Really `Animals` (should be named `Animal`) looks abstract to me (does it really make sense to create an instance of `Animal`?). You might want to consider making `Animal` a protocol instead, and letting conforming types define their own `name` and `age` properties with whatever default values you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Alternatively using protocols (and generics) over classes

You will most likely create instances of `Cat`:s and `Dog`:s, but you might not want to do so for abstract weird `Animal`:s. An alternative for `Animal` being a common superclass is letting it be a protocol.

```
protocol Animal {
    static var species: String { get }
    var name: String? { get }
    var age: Int { get set }
    var details: String { get }
}

extension Animal {
    static var species: String { return "\(self)".lowercased() }

    // since all the properties used in 'details' are blueprinted,
    // we might as well supply a default implementation of it.
    var details: String {
        return "This animal is a \(Self.species)\(name.map{ " named \($0)" } ?? ""), aged \(age)."
    }
}

struct Dog: Animal {
    let name: String?
    var age: Int

    init(age: Int, name: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

var myDog = Dog(age: 3, name: "Fred")
print(myDog.details) // This animal is a dog named Fred, aged 3.
myDog.age = 4 // grats to Fred!
print(myDog.details) // This animal is a dog named Fred, aged 4.

let wildDog = Dog(age: 6) // never named ...
print(wildDog.details) // This animal is a dog, aged 3.
```

Note that I've chosen to use a class property `species` to name the species of each animal, and reserved the instance property `name` for those animals that are given a name; say, your dear dog named `Fred` (rather than your dear dog named `dog`).

Using protocols will also make it natural choice to prefer generics over typed abstract types (the latter which might be tempting when using a common superclass):

```
struct Cat: Animal {
    let name: String?
    var age: Int

    init(age: Int, name: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

var wildCat = Cat(age: 2)

func yieldBirthday<T: Animal>(for animal: inout T) {
    print(animal.details)
    animal.age += 1
    print("This \(T.species) now had a birthday!")
    print(animal.details)
}

yieldBirthday(for: &myDog)
/* This animal is a dog named Fred, aged 4.
   This dog now had a birthday!
   This animal is a dog named Fred, aged 5. */

yieldBirthday(for: &wildCat)
/* This animal is a cat, aged 2.
   This cat now had a birthday!
   This animal is a cat, aged 3. */
```

Comment: This is indeed a very "Swifty" solution

Comment: How can I know more about protocols? That seems the ultimate solution!

Comment: @Ben I'd suggest you start with the [Swift Language Guide - Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html). Onwards from there, simply google for "swift protocols" and you'll find numerous references and blog posts covering different interesting aspects, use cases and examples on the subject. Also have a look at related WWDC14, 15 and 16 talks on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

If you want stored, not computed, properties, you can set `name` in the *initializer*, like this:

```
class Animal {
    let name: String
    var age: Int = 0
    /* designated initializer: fully initializes all instance properties */
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    func details() -> String {
        return "This animal is a \(name) and has \(age) years old."
    }
}


class Dog : Animal {
    /* designated initializer of subclass: must call a designated
       initializer from its immediate superclass                   */
    init() {
        super.init(name: "dog")
    }
}

class Cat : Animal {
    /* ... */
    init() {
        super.init(name: "cat")
    }
}

let myAnimal = Dog()
```

This mechanism ensures that `name` is set from only one place, and is passed to the initializer explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve will be to use "template method pattern"

```
class Animals {
    lazy var name : String = self.defaultName
    var defaultName:String { return "default" }

    func Details()-> String{
        return "This animal is a \(name) and has \(age) years old."
    }
}

class Dogs : Animals {
    override var defaultName:String { return "dog" }
}
```

Another approach will be to create `init` method for each subclass and override the default values

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this, by making an initializer to set the name (with a default value):

```
class Animal: CustomStringConvertible {
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    init(name: String = "default", age: Int = 0) { // FIXME: Does a default age of 0 make sense?
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    public var description: String {
        return "This animal is a \(name) and is \(age) years old."
    }
}


class Dog: Animal {
    init() {
        super.init(name: "Dog")
    }
}

class Cat: Animal {
    init() {
        super.init(name: "Cat")
    }
}

var myAnimal = Dog()
print (myAnimal)
```